# VBA not saving changes made in the code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a xlsm workbook and I've made some changes in the code and it runs perfectly. However the changes I've made in the code aren't being saved, and the next time I open the workbook I have to make those changes again.
I'm using excel 2016 and the file is in a shared folder of one drive.

Can anyone please suggest a fix for this?

Comment: Did you get any errors when trying to save?

Comment: Are you using the Save command in the VBE, or in Excel? I've seen situations where the VBE's Save command will not save the changes (but if I recall, that was Excel 2007/2010). Try saving from Excel's UI, and see if the changes are persisted. You might also want to check the file isn't marked as read only, and that you have write permissions to the shared location.

Comment: @bassfader No i dont get any errors. it seems to save successfully when I do ctrl + s or click the save button. but then again next time i open it nothing is saved

Comment: @ThunderFrame I've been saving using ctrl + S and also by clicking the save button. both in VBE and in excel. And I do have the permissions because I set up the shared location with this file.

Comment: @UmmadArif What you describe is almost impossible. What happens if you save the file to a new local folder e.g. Desktop. Dose it save there with macros? Re-safe it by using the *safe as* command from menu and make sure you select *xlsm* as file type in the *save as* dialog.

Comment: @Peh the file is saved as expected when I save it in a new local folder. However I have a live connection with a tableau workbook based on this file thats why I would like the file in the shared one drive to be saved after I modify my VBA code.

Comment: @UmmadArif Then this is not  a Excel issue but a share, access or user rights issue I would say. What you can try is using *save as* to re-save it with a new filename into the share. If this doesn't work too then you definitely have issues with the access rights.

Comment: same problem with immediate window, trying to kill the "research" pain.